# Building intuition for the outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I’m trying to build intuition for the outer measure $m^\ast$ and considering some simple examples. Now I’ve chosen $A= [2,4] \times [1,3]$ to be the subset of $\Bbb R^2$ whose measure I want to get. This is a simple square which should have measure $4$.

Now If I cover $A$ with say $I_1 =[1,3] \times [0,4]$ and $I_2 =[1,6] \times [1,3]$ the Lebesgue cover $\mathcal{F}=\{I_1,I_2\}$ would be what I have now.

Now by definition the outer measure is defined as $$m^\ast (A)=\inf\{\sum_{I\in \mathcal{F}}\ell(I) \mid \text{ $\mathcal{F} $ covers $A$} \}$$

which in this example would be the same as saying $$m^\ast(A)  =\inf\{\sum_{k=1}^2 \ell(I_k) \mid A \subset \bigcup_{k}^2 I_k\}$$

Now I’m confused about what is the set $\{\sum_{k=1}^2 \ell(I_k) \mid A \subset \bigcup_{k}^2 I_k\} $? I can clearly compute $$\sum_{k=1}^2 \ell(I_k)  = \ell(I_1) + \ell(I_2) = 8 +10=18$$

So $\{\sum_{k=1}^2 \ell(I_k) \mid A \subset \bigcup_{k}^2 I_k\}  = \{18\} $ and $\inf\{18\} = 18$? However this is wrong since the outer measure should be $4$?

Here is btw the visualization of the above situation

[image]

Comment: This is not a confusion about your intuition but about what the infimum is taken of. You need to take not just this covering that you came up with - but *all* coverings from $\mathcal F$ - some of them a lot more finely-grained than yours, and then take the infimum across *all* of those. For some of those coverings, the total sum will be *very* close (or maybe even equal?) to $4$.

Comment: But $\mathcal{F}$ only has two elements? Aren’t I considering them both here?

Comment: @Georgi I guess the confusion comes from the fact that you are defining $\mathcal{F}$ to have only $2$ elements. In the definition of outer measure, $\mathcal{F}$ has infinitely many element, and you cannot really take an $\mathcal{F}$ with only $2$ elements and preserve the definition of outer measure

Comment: Sorry, my typo. $\mathcal F$ is only one of the coverings, and you need to take the infimum across *all* coverings (of $A$). Some of them will be a lot less "coarse"/a lot "finer" than $\mathcal F$ - bringing the infimum down. In fact, another covering is $\{A\}$ ($A$ covers itself!), or you can cover $A$ by neatly laid out squares of $0.01\times 0.01$ in size etc.